# how to use nodejs packages in meteor

Tags: node.js, meteor, meteorite

how to use nodejs package in meteor app.

i tried to install module in app directory it is showing error

**npm install skimlinksjs**

```
npm WARN package.json node@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json node@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/skimlinksjs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/skimlinksjs
npm WARN engine skimlinksjs@0.0.1: wanted: {"node":"~0.6.15"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.24","npm":"1.3.21"})
skimlinksjs@0.0.1 ../../node_modules/skimlinksjs
```

What is this error and how to use it in the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do that, and remove the `node_modules` directory. Most node modules will not work like that due to Meteor's file wrapping and ordering. They just won't load properly.

To use a node module:

- Grab `npm` package via `mrt add npm` command.
- Add `packages.json` file with the list of necessary packages, for example:

```
{
  "candle": "0.4.0",
  "oauth":  "0.9.11"
}
```

- Afterwards, you can require the package with `Meteor.require('packagename');`.

Comment: + sometimes the wrapped up node modules can be found on atmosphere.meteor.com too